# Dynamically disable/enable tab of p:accordionPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want only single Tab (not entire accordion panel) to be enabled or disabled dynamically.
I tried following approach, here is my code:

index.xhtml

```html
<p:accordionPanel id="accordionPanelId" widgetVar="accordionPanelWidget">
   <p:tab id="tab1" title="First Tab">
       <h:outputText value="Contents of Tab1"/>
       <h:form>
         <p:commandButton value="Enable Tab2" action="#{tabBean.buttonAction}" update=":accordionPanelId:tab2"/>
       </h:form>
   </p:tab>
            
   <p:tab id="tab2" title="Second Tab" disabled="#{tableBean.disableTab}">
      <h:outputText value="Contents of Tab2"/> 
   </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

TabBean.java

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TabBean implements Serializable {
    
    private boolean disableTab=true;

    public boolean isDisableTab() {
        return disableTab;
    }

    public void setDisableTab(boolean disableTab) {
        this.disableTab = disableTab;
    }
    
    public void buttonAction()
    {
        disableTab = false;
    }
    
}
```

With the above approach Tab2's content is showing but the Tab Header is still freezes,
May be this is not a god approach to achieve this...
Please suggest any other way or changes in this approach.

**EDIT**: The above approach is working fine if I update entire Accordion panel as follows:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Enable Tab2" action="#{tabBean.buttonAction}" update=":accordionPanelId"/>
```

But I don't want to update all the tabs.

Comment: I have tried your example, what i found the ID gives to only tab area, not tab header, that why it is not updating tab header, you need to either update all, or remove css class(.ui-helper-hidden) form tab header by javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `disabled` attribute of the tab to the `disableTab` backing bean variable that you'll toggle on the server side. To reflect the changes you made on the server side, you then ajax-update the `<p:accordionPanel/>` on the client side. Using your current setup, the only changes you'll need to make is:

1. Bind the `disabled` attribute to the backing bean variable you've setup

   ```
      <p:tab id="tab2" title="Second Tab" disabled="#{tabBean.disableTab}">
          <h:outputText value="Contents of Tab2"/> 
      </p:tab>
   ```
2. Automatically switch to the tab after enabling it with the javascript API

   ```
      <p:tab id="tab1" title="First Tab">
         <h:outputText value="Contents of Tab1"/>
            <h:form>
              <p:commandButton value="Enable Tab2" oncomplete="accordionPanelWidget.select(2)" action="#{tabBean.buttonAction}" update=":accordionPanelId:tab2"/>
           </h:form>
      </p:tab>
   ```

Comment: Hi kolossus..,
Thanks for reply, sorry I forgot to bind tab disabled to bean variable. Now I did but the problem is the tab is not updating correctly, Please see new edit to the question.

Comment: @Kishor, what does "not updating correctly" mean? It's not reflecting the change? Why don't you just update the tab you're interested in updating?

Comment: have tried the example??
Its enabling the Tab Content but not Tab Header(The place where you click to open the tab). The header is FROZEN/DISABLED.
you just try it once you'll understand.

Answer (score -1):

You have to update all the accordionPanel in order to enable/disable tabs. In this case you'll have to update accordionPanelId. However, you can use dynamic="true" attribute in accordionPanel to avoid update the parts that aren't rendered.

Comment: Please read the original question. It is all already in there and that OP does not want this.

Comment: However, you can use dynamic="true" attribute in accordionPanel to avoid update the parts that aren't rendered.